# Poor character recognition results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ocr

I'm trying to read six-digit number from an Image. I use tensorflow/keras for training.
This is the model I came up with for this:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same", input_shape=(20, 20, 1), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(500, activation="relu"))

model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), batch_size=40, epochs=30, verbose=1)
```

I took more than 97,000 samples, 30% of which I put to the test.
After training:

[image]

As you can see, the results on the samples are very good, but when I use the same samples for testing, I get a wrong result of almost every 10 items.

I matched the training and test samples and they were all the same. This is preprocessing section:

```
letter_image = img_number[y: y + h, x: x + w]
letter_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(letter_image, 5, 5, 5, 5, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(255, 255, 255))
letter_image = cv2.cvtColor(letter_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
letter_image = helper.resize_to_fit(letter_image, 20, 20)
raw = letter_image
letter_image = np.expand_dims(letter_image, axis=2)
letter_image = np.expand_dims(letter_image, axis=0)
prediction = cheque_number_model.predict(letter_image)
letter = cheque_number_label.inverse_transform(prediction)[0]
```

I'd be very grateful for any suggestion.
Thanks and also sorry about my English.

Comment: This is most likely to be something related to preprocessing of the test data. Please post more code so we can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I added the preprocessing section.

Comment: i can't see your full val loss and val acc but if its in same range as the final results (around 0.99) for previous epochs, try early stopping (you can look at EarlyStopping callback or train for less epochs)

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did not think less epochs could help. I will try It. thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are few points you should consider for improving the accuracy.

1. Try to increase the train-test split.
2. The layer that you have added in Conv2D has very small shape of 5x5 where as your input is 20x20. Think about what you are doing, you are essentially cropping out or neglecting important features of the data.
3. As you are keeping on adding new layers the shape is remaining same but the number of neurons are increasing which is absurd.
4. Also think what max pooling does to your input shape.

Please look into these 4 points and do changes accordingly.
You shall see an improvement. Kindly get back to me with the results.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm really appreciated. I do not know many concepts of Conv. about Second point: should I increase shape or increase the input size? and about third point: did you mean second layer of Conv2 should be remove?

Comment: Change this (Conv2D(20, (5, 5)...) to ((Conv2D(20, (20, 20)...) for the second point and then reduce the (20,20) by let us say 2 or 3 for the subsequent layer. For the third point, no I do not mean that you should remove the second layer, I mean only change the size of it as previously mentioned. Get back to me if u need anything else.